# When CDI injection into POJO should work? (GlassFish v3)

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

When I inject EJB 3.1 beans into POJO created by @Inject then injection works. When I construct POJO on my own then it doesn't (Glassfish v3). Is it correct behavior?

My classes (in EJB module):

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
@Named
public class NewSingletonBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("NewSingletonBean INIT");
    }

}
```

_

```
public class MyPOJO {
        @Inject NewSingletonBean newSingletonBean;

        public void sth(){
            System.out.println("EJB injected into POJO: " + (newSingletonBean != null));
        }
}
```

This **does not work**:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
@DependsOn(value="NewSingletonBean")
public class NewSingletonBean2 {

    @Inject NewSingletonBean newSingletonBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("NewSingletonBean2 INIT");
        System.out.println("EJB injected into EJB: " + (newSingletonBean != null));
        MyPOJO p = new MyPOJO();
        p.sth();
    }

}
```

_

And this **works OK**:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
@DependsOn(value="NewSingletonBean")
public class NewSingletonBean2 {

    @Inject NewSingletonBean newSingletonBean;
    @Inject MyPOJO p;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("NewSingletonBean2 INIT");
        System.out.println("EJB injected into EJB: " + (newSingletonBean != null));
        p.sth();
    }

}
```

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1.

dist directory structure:

```
│   CDITest.ear
│
└───gfdeploy
    └───CDITest
        ├───CDITest-ejb_jar
        │   │   .netbeans_automatic_build
        │   │   .netbeans_update_resources
        │   │
        │   ├───META-INF
        │   │       beans.xml
        │   │       MANIFEST.MF
        │   │
        │   └───tries
        │           MyPOJO.class
        │           NewSingletonBean.class
        │           NewSingletonBean2.class
        │
        ├───CDITest-war_war
        │   │   index.jsp
        │   │
        │   ├───META-INF
        │   │       MANIFEST.MF
        │   │
        │   └───WEB-INF
        │       └───classes
        │               .netbeans_automatic_build
        │               .netbeans_update_resources
        │
        └───META-INF
                MANIFEST.MF
```

Unpacked EAR structure:

```
│   CDITest-ejb.jar
│   CDITest-war.war
│
└───META-INF
        MANIFEST.MF
```

Unpacked EJB module jar structure:

```
├───META-INF
│       beans.xml
│       MANIFEST.MF
│
└───tries
        MyPOJO.class
        NewSingletonBean.class
        NewSingletonBean2.class
```

Is it correct behavior?

Comment: I guess you've already asked about this in comments to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165482/cdi-inject-ejb-into-pojo-on-glassfish-v3

Comment: Yes, but it was question in comments so not full stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following part might be an answer to your question:

As per [CDI 1.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/web_beans-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

**3.7. Bean constructors**

> When the container instantiates a bean class, it calls the *bean
> constructor*. The bean constructor is a constructor of the bean class.
>
> The application may call bean constructors directly. However, **if the
> application directly instantiates the bean**, no parameters are passed
> to the constructor by the container; the returned object is not bound
> to any context; **no dependencies are injected by the container**; and
> the lifecycle of the new instance is not managed by the container.

HTH!

Answer (score 4):

It is correct behaviour, because DI works only for container-managed beans, not for that ones, you've created yourself.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you cite specification or sth?